# Python Dropbox Api : Write CSV

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

please how can i save results on a csv file to dropbox using dropbox api

this is how i save a file on my local laptop :

```
    with open(r'success.csv', 'a') as success_file:
        success_file.write('\n{},{}'.format(cleanstr2, cleanstr4))
```

But using dropbox api, i know only how to read a file :

```
# read data
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("mytoken")
_, res = dbx.files_download("/file1/file2/filefinal.csv")
stream = io.BytesIO(res.content)
dfs = pd.read_csv(stream)
```

How can i write/upload using dropbox api please

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using [the `files_download` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_download) in [the official Dropbox API v2 Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) to download a file.

You can similarly use [the `files_upload` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_upload) to upload a file. There's [an example of doing so here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/fc72aaa95fa474171c3b4a42ee08f06841e65108/example/back-up-and-restore/backup-and-restore-example.py#L26).